# How to find quantiles of an empirical cumulative density function (ECDF)

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am using `ecdf()` function to calculate empirical cumulative density function (ECDF) from some random samples:

```
set.seed(0)
X = rnorm(100)
P = ecdf(X)
```

Now `P` gives ECDF and we could plot it:

```
plot(P)
abline(h = 0.6, lty = 3)
```

[image: ecdf]

**My question is**: how can I find the sample value `x`, such that `P(x) = 0.6`, i.e., the 0.6-quantile of ECDF, or the x-coordinate of the intersection point of ECDF and `h = 0.6`?

Comment: Could you provide any example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to give statistical tutoring sessions. If you are confused about your stats HW then you should post on CrossValidated.com and use the self-study tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the following, I will not use `ecdf()`, as it is easy to obtain empirical cumulative density function (ECDF) ourselves.

First, we sort samples `X` in ascending order:

```
X <- sort(X)
```

ECDF at those samples takes function values:

```
e_cdf <- 1:length(X) / length(X)
```

We could then sketch ECDF by:

```
plot(X, e_cdf, type = "s")
abline(h = 0.6, lty = 3)
```

[image]

Now, we are looking for the first value of `X`, such that `P(X) >= 0.6`. This is just:

```
X[which(e_cdf >= 0.6)[1]]
# [1] 0.2290196
```

Since our data are sampled from standard normal distribution, the theoretical quantile is

```
qnorm(0.6)
# [1] 0.2533471
```

So our result is quite close.

---

## Extension

Since **the inverse of CDF is quantile function** (for example, the inverse of `pnorm()` is `qnorm()`), one may guess the inverse of ECDF as sample quantile, i,e, the inverse `ecdf()` is `quantile()`. This is not true!

**ECDF is a staircase / step function, and it does not have inverse**. If we rotate ECDF around `y = x`, the resulting curve is not a mathematical function. **So sample quantile is has nothing to do with ECDF**.

For `n` sorted samples, **sample quantile function is in fact a linear interpolation function** of `(x, y)`, with:

- x-values being `seq(0, 1, length = n)`;
- y-values being sorted samples.

**We can define our own version of sample quantile function** by:

```
my_quantile <- function(x, prob) {
  if (is.unsorted(x)) x <- sort(x)
  n <- length(x)
  approx(seq(0, 1, length = n), x, prob)$y
  }
```

Let's have a test:

```
my_quantile(X, 0.6)
# [1] 0.2343171

quantile(X, prob = 0.6, names = FALSE)
# [1] 0.2343171
```

Note that result is different from what we get from `X[which(e_cdf >= 0.6)[1]]`.

It is for this reason, that I refuse to use `quantile()` in my answer.