# How to get quantile from category count in R?

Tags: r, quantile

For example, I have a sample data of human height in a DataFrame:

```
df <- data_frame(height = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9), number = c(20, 30, 50, 30, 20))
```

How can I calculate the 90% quantile of this sample?

I know ggplot2 has a function can plot the ecdf of the sample:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = height, y = number)) + stat_ecdf()
```

but I only need a specified quantile not the plot.

I could repeat each `height` `number` times to make a vector and use the `quantile` function on the vector, but as the `number` getting larger, this method seems to be very inefficient.

EDIT:

It seems `stat_ecdf` are not supposed to be used in this way, and when data distribution is skewed:

```
df <- data_frame(height = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9), number = c(100, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

only quantile of the repeated vector gives the desired result:

```
quantile(c(rep(1.5,100), rep(1.6,2), rep(1.7,3), rep(1.8,4), rep(1.9,5)))
```

Comment: you can use  quantile(df$height ,prob = 0.9)

Comment: If you do not want you implement your own custom quantile function, I would use you use your own suggestion. While it may seem and be inefficient, are you actually in a situation where this is problematic?

Comment: `quantile(rep(df$height, df$number), prob = 0.9)` ; related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225843/compute-sample-statistics-for-a-data-vector-with-ties-which-is-stored-as-a-frequ