# Why getting similar output for quantile in r?

Tags: r

I have two diffent columns

```
a = c(65.96924, 7.084438, 81.65288 )

b= c(2197.62974660844, 1934.40212085843, 1939.64438773692, 
    )`
```

They are different, but I wonder why I go similar output when applying:

```
   quants <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 51)
   ecdf(a)(quantile(a, quants))
   ecdf(b)(quantile(b, quants))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be better understood if you calculate the ecdf by hand instead of using the `ecdf()` function, which is just a step function that increases up by 1/n at each of the n data points. Since both are the same length you get the same result.

```
quants <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 51)

A <- sort(a)
B <- sort(b)

A_ecdf <- 1:length(A)/length(A)
B_ecdf <- 1:length(B)/length(B)

plot(A, A_ecdf, type = "s", col = 1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(B, B_ecdf, type = "s", col = 2)
```

Though I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, a possible solution from [How to find quantiles of an empirical cumulative density function (ECDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537311/how-to-find-quantiles-of-an-empirical-cumulative-density-function-ecdf) may be:

```
my_quantile <- function(x, prob) {
  n <- length(x)
  approx(seq(0, 1, length = n), x, prob)$y
}

my_quantile(A, quants)
my_quantile(B, quants)
```

Comment: @bicton - your question was why you got the same output when applying your code. It is not clear what else you are trying to do. If you have a separate question, please edit this one or create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function of the quantiles itself and not of the distribution e.g. `ecdf(b)(2000)`. By definition, you end up with a straight line.

Comment: Just an example to get a value of the `ecdf` to show that it returned other values for a and b.